# Is it possible to split aggregated text into multiple sqlite3 columns?

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to pivot rows into columns on an SQLite3 database. This is not a native function on this DB, so I thought it could have been possible to manage the task via cyclically running a set instr/substr combination (in a CTE).
However, the CTE still returns a temp table with individual row results so this is so far [impossible](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ndPt4PZbwjf1JTJbtpDE2S/2).

Hardcoding the number of columns in a case statement, as I previously did [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/266661/revisions) is not an option as my input might not have a fixed number of destination columns.

Given the dataset proposed in the example above, the desired outcome would be something like:

```
| ANCHOR | TARGET-1 | TARGET-2 | TARGET-3 | TARGET-X
| 123    | URL-A    | URL-B    | URL-C    | ....
| 1AA    | URL-A1   | URL-B1   | URL-C1
```

Perhaps I'm overthinking something, or I might need to simply give up doing some post elaboration after the initial group_concat elsewhere (e.g., in Excel?).
Any idea?